# Azure app service connection string disappears on redeployment

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, github-actions

I add a connection string to my app service (configuration > connection strings > + New connection string > Save), and this works. But when I redeploy through my CI/CD github workflow, the connection string is gone.

Before a new deployment:

[image: Before]

After a new deployement:

[image: After]

My workflow file:

```yaml
on: [push]
name: workflow
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2 # checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your workflow can access it.
      - run: dotnet --version
      - run: dotnet tool restore
      - run: dotnet run --project tests/Server/Server.Tests.fsproj
  build-and-deploy:
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/deploy'
    needs: test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: 'Checkout Github Action'
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: 'Login via Azure CLI'
        uses: azure/login@v1
        with:
          creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}

      - name: 'Restore'
        run: dotnet tool restore

      - name: 'Deploy'
        run: dotnet run azure
```

Comment: It's hard to answer this question without seeing your workflow file

Comment: I'll update with the workflow script. So you think the problem is that the deployment wipes the setting in azure,  @AbdulNiyasPM?

Answer (score 0):

I have deployed the `.NET Core App` to `Azure App service` using `GitHub Actions`.

- Added new Connection String in `Configuration` => `Connection Strings` as you have mentioned.
- When I tried to `Sync` (Redeploy) from `Deployment Center`, got the below alert.

[image]

- It clearly says that old deployment changes will be updated with the new one.
- But for me the `Connection String` is not missing.
- While creating the App Service, Initially  `Disable` the `GitHub Actions` settings.

[image]

- Later, Connect to `GitHub` from Deployment Center.

[image]

- If we don't want to miss any `configurations` which are done after deployment. Instead of Re-deploying the App using `Sync` option, click on `Disconnect`.

[image]

- Re-connect and Build the workflow again.
- You can see the available `Connection Strings`.

[image]